# Refer to passed in variable in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parent_work_copy(track_number) {    
      document.form1.track_(track_number)_name.value=document.form1.track_(track_number)_parent_work.value;
   }
</script>
```

If the link below is clicked, I want the line inside of the parent_work_copy function to be modified to:

```
document.form1.track_5_name.value=document.form1.track_5_parent_work.value
```

```
<a href="javascript:parent_work_copy(5)">copy to track</a>
```

How to do this?

Comment: No, you do not want to modify source code on the fly. Wrong approach. You want to write code which can take a variable and act accordingly, without modifying itself.

Comment: Variables are your friends, they'll store data for you. Try `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript object keys works as string

```
 document.form1["track_"+track_number+"_name"].value=document.form1["track_"+track_number+"_parent_work"].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

`document.form1['track_'+track_number+'_name'].value`